# How to use dplyr to create a new variable based on a function result in a grouped data?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data.frame:

```
set.seed(7)
data = data.frame(a = rnorm(100),
                  b = rnorm(100),
                  c = rnorm(100))
```

Then I reshaped it:

```
long = reshape2::melt(data, measure.vars = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

Then, I'd like to test each a,b, and c variable for **UnitRoot** presence. So I use ur.df from Urca package. Here's my question:

How can I use *dplyr* to create a new indicator variable, say 1 or 0, to stay whether is unitroot or not. I'm thinking in something likes this:

```
output = long %>% group_by(variable) %>% 
  do(UR = summary(ur.df(.$value, type = c("trend"), selectlags = "BIC"))) %>% 
  summarise(variable, tau = UR@teststat[1], 
            tau_cri = UR@cval[1,3],
            URT = if_else(UR@teststat[1] < UR@cval[1,3], 
                                    1, 0))
```

But last piece of code just generate a new data.frame (output) with each group variable, i.e. "a, b and c" with an indicator whether if has or not a unitroot. But what I want is to generate a new variable in the same data.frame, I mean in **long**. I want this because I might have to split my data.frame according to that indicator (May be here, you have another idea to get the same result in other way different to what I'm thinking about. That's welcome too, but I'd appreciate if you know how to do what I want).

PD: the result from my code is this:

```
  variable   tau tau_cri   URT
  <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        -5.23   -3.15     1
2 b        -7.83   -3.15     1
3 c        -5.89   -3.15     1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one different approach. We can create two new columns, one with `ur.df` object which is stored as a `list` so that it can be used later to do some other calculation if needed and other one (`URT`) which is an indicator variable representing whether it is `unitroot` or not.

```
library(dplyr)
library(urca)

long %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(ur.df_obj = list(summary(ur.df(value, type = "trend", selectlags = "BIC"))),
           URT = +(purrr::map_lgl(ur.df_obj, ~.x@teststat[1] < .x@cval[1,3])))


#   variable  value ur.df_obj   URT
#   <fct>     <dbl> <list>    <int>
# 1 a         2.29  <sumurca>     1
# 2 a        -1.20  <sumurca>     1
# 3 a        -0.694 <sumurca>     1
# 4 a        -0.412 <sumurca>     1
# 5 a        -0.971 <sumurca>     1
# 6 a        -0.947 <sumurca>     1
# 7 a         0.748 <sumurca>     1
# 8 a        -0.117 <sumurca>     1
# 9 a         0.153 <sumurca>     1
#10 a         2.19  <sumurca>     1
# … with 290 more rows
```